# Getting the results Null not included

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to get the list of persons who has a NULL values on the person_discharge_date but I also need to consider the create_date(get its latest) so that the name of the person would not show up twice.

For my question, how do you also query where it will only show person_discharge_date with null values based also on the latest create_date?

I have trouble showing only values that have null on person_discharge_date and vise versa.

**My Intake table**

```
IntakeTable
    intake_id|  person_id |person_discharge_date   |create_date
    ---------|------------|------------------------|-----------------------
    2263     |  2289      |2010-06-28 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:54.503
    2264     |  2289      |2010-08-28 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:54.547
    4465     |  4489      |2011-02-12 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:54.563
    1267     |  1218      |2009-12-11 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:54.707
    7373     |  2348      |2010-06-03 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:55.297
    4463     |  4429      |2011-09-20 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:57.133
    6164     |  6129      |2011-05-18 00:00:00.000 |2012-04-17 13:41:57.143
    12377    |  1888      |NULL                    |2013-01-05 22:12:41.990
    12378    |  5899      |NULL                    |2013-01-05 22:17:02.957
    12379    |  5899      |NULL                    |2013-01-05 22:18:02.957
```

**This is my person table**

```
PersonTable
person_id|  fname     |
---------|------------|
2289     |  marge     |
4489     |  shell     |
1218     |  linkoln   |
2348     |  abe       |
4429     |  mark      |
6129     |  doom      |
1888     |  lorde     |
5899     |  braddy    |
```

This is my query but there is something missing with this because I need to get the latest create date of the person, so that the person will not show twice from the results.

```
select intake_id, person_id, person_discharge_date from intaketable it inner join persontable pt it.person_id = pt.person_id    WHERE person_discharge_date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hint:  `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`?  Perhaps you should show what results you want and any queries you have tried.

Comment: Explain what "trouble" you had.

Comment: I do not know how to query where it I will only show a person that has a null values on person_discharge_date and vise versa (show result not including null values)

Comment: Could you provide expected result?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you make a query where it will only include the Null from the
>   results on person_discharge_date

Check for `IS NULL` in your `WHERE` condition for the said column in question saying

```
WHERE person_discharge_date IS NULL
```

You can use `group by` and get the `max()` like

```
select person.*, xxx.person_discharge_date 
from person p join (
select person_id, person_discharge_date,
   max(create_date) as latest
from Intake
where person_discharge_date is null  
group by person_id ) xxx on p.person_id = xxx.person_id;
```

Comment: But I also need to get the latest create_date for the person_id so that it will not display the same name twice.

Comment: the 'person_discharge_date' is not included in the 'group by' should it be included there ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to this with the help of mixing the two codes from Rahul and other site

```
SELECT  pi.person_id,
        pi.intake_id,
        pi.person_discharge_date,
        pi.create_date 
    FROM intake pi INNER JOIN (select patient_id, MAX(create_date) 
    as LatestDate FROM intake group by patient_id) 
    pati ON pi.person_id = pati.person_id AND pi.Create_DATE = 
    pati.latestdate 
    WHERE person_discharge_date IS NULL
```